# Wait for NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: to finish loading, and then

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have the following:

```
NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:apiURLString];
NSData *apiResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:apiURL];
```

How do I fire some code only after the loading is complete? In case it helps, the code I'm trying to execute at that point is a `NSNotificationCenter` notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dataWithContentsOfURL` method blocks until it has finished loading the data. So you can just add your code at the end of the snippet you showed.

Comment: A corollary of this would be: don't use +dataWithContentsOfURL for non-file URLs, since it will block on a network request.

Comment: I thought so as well, but the notification I fire afterwards is read at a time when the data is still not on the server... Where should I look then?

Comment: @MorganWilde You might have another problem then. If you have access to the server then I would look at the access log and see if the request was actually successful. It might not be.

Comment: @MorganWilde You can also use `NSData`'s `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` method .. then you will probably get some more hints in the returned error object in case anything goes wrong. Post more info here and we will be able to give a better answer.

Comment: @St3fan as it turns out I wasn't updating the `NSArray` property I was supposed to update. It's all good :)